# How to fix the following compilation error?

Tags: android

> Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties.

Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: Try setting .class compatibility to 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties. Then from main menu, Project -> Clean...

If that doesn't solve it, try restarting Eclipse.